# vhdl invalid memory access (dangling accesses or stack size too small)

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I'm trying to recreate a traffic light. And as it seems I have some kind of loop in my program since this message comes up whenever I run my testbench. I know for a fact that the loop in the testbench was okay, at least not the main problem, since once I commented it out, the error message came up again. Once I commented out the `ampel` (traffic light), the error wasn't there anymore. So my guess is that something is wrong with my `ampel` entity, but I can't find what it is.

Here the code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ampel is

    port (
      clk, reset : in std_logic;
      rot, gelb, gruen : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
  end ampel;

architecture rtl of ampel is
    
type t_zustand is (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h);

signal zustand : t_zustand;
signal timer : integer;

begin
rot <= "1111";
    process is
    begin
        wait on clk until clk = '1';
            timer <= timer + 1;
            if reset = '0' then
                zustand <= a;
                rot <= "1111";
                gelb <= "0000";
                gruen <= "0000";
                timer <= 2;
            else 
                case zustand is
                    when a => 
                        rot <= "1111"; 
                        gelb <= "0000"; 
                        gruen <= "0000"; 
                        if timer = 5  then
                            zustand   <= b;
                        end if;
                        
                    when b => 
                        rot <= "0101"; 
                        gelb <= "1010"; 
                        gruen <= "0000";
                        if timer = 10 then
                            zustand   <= c;
                        end if;
                        
                    when c => 
                        rot <= "0101";
                        gelb <= "0000"; 
                        gruen <= "1010";
                        if timer = 40 then
                            zustand   <= d;
                        end if;
                        
                    when d =>
                        rot <= "0101";
                        gelb <= "1010";
                        gruen <= "0000";
                        if timer = 45 then
                            zustand   <= e;
                        end if;
                        
                    when e => 
                        rot <= "1111";
                        gelb <= "0000";
                        gruen <= "0000";
                        if timer = 50 then
                            zustand   <= b;
                        end if;
                        
                    when f => 
                        rot <= "1010";
                        gelb <= "0101";
                        gruen <= "0000";
                        if timer = 55 then
                            zustand   <= b;
                        end if;
                        
                    when g => 
                        rot <= "1010";
                        gelb <= "0000";
                        gruen <= "0101";
                        if timer = 85 then
                            zustand   <= b;
                        end if;
                        
                    when h =>
                        rot <= "1010";
                        gelb <= "0101";
                        gruen <= "0000";
                        if timer = 90 then
                            zustand   <= b;
                        end if;
                        
                end case;
            end if;
    end process;
    
end rtl ;
```

The testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ampel_tb is
end ampel_tb;

architecture testbench of ampel_tb is

    component ampel is 
    port(
        clk, reset : in std_logic;
        rot, gelb, gruen : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
    end component;

signal clk, reset : std_logic;
signal rot, gelb, gruen : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin
   ampel0: ampel port map(clk => clk, reset => reset, rot => rot, gelb => gelb, gruen => gruen);
    
   process begin
        reset <= '0';
        clk <= '0';
        wait for 500 ms;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for 500 ms;
        reset <= '1';
        clk <= '0';
        wait for 500 ms;
        for I in 0 to 180 loop 
            clk <= '1';
            wait for 500 ms;
            clk <= '0';
            wait for 500 ms;
        end loop;
        assert false report "End of test";
        wait;
    end process;
   
end testbench;
```

Comment: Can you please show the exact error message you get?

Comment: See the [ghdl documentation](https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/Simulation.html#cmdoption-ghdl-max-stack-alloc) where the command line simulation option `--max-static-alloc=0` would turn a warning off.

Comment: What does ghdl --version report? I get no errors with `GHDL 1.0-dev (v0.37.0-1065-g6bf4e741) [Dunoon edition]` Might be time for an upgrade? (+1 for a decent testcase btw)

Comment: the error message is :
"invalid memory access (dangling accesses or stack size too small)"
"simulation failed"

Also my version is:
GHDL 0.29.1 (20100301) [Sokcho edition]

So yea, i might have to update it

Comment: GHDL has transformed radically since then! Time for a visit to https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl

Comment: I know i might sound stupid and naive and so on, but i never rly got in touche with github. so i'm a bit confused where i should start to download/update my ghdl. I downloaded it with an exe so that was easy but i cant seem to find an exe in the git. So it would be nice if u could give me some kinda tutorial how to navigate in the ghdl git so i can update my ghdl.

Comment: Scroll down to "Getting GHDL" from that link, there should be instructions there.

Comment: See also https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting/Releases.html